# PL/SQL and PHP encode encrypt returning different value

Tags: php, encryption, plsql

PHP
result RWOorls4A/WOiWnGkNT1ZA==

```
    <?php
$str= "1668621";
$password="1987"; 
$encrypted_string=openssl_encrypt($str,"AES-128-ECB",$password);
```

PLSQL
result 0E805DCF65571F4AAB898328B51B4034

```
 DECLARE
  input_string VARCHAR2(50):= '1668621';
  encryption_key raw(32);
  encrypted_string raw(2000);
  encryption_type pls_integer := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES128 + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_ECB + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;

  
BEGIN

  -- First the key is hashed with md5 to make it a 128bit key:
  encryption_key := DBMS_CRYPTO.Hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('1987'), DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_MD5);

   encrypted_string := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT( 
src => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(input_string), typ => encryption_type, key => encryption_key);
```

Is there a way to get same result in php and in PL/SQL?

Comment: You shouldn't use [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_(ECB)). If you're implementing code that handles encryption, you _really_ want to make sure that you read the documentation and understand what you are doing. Otherwise, you are very likely to make mistakes that allow attackers to break your encryption.

Comment: The problem is that I must use ECB because of php code that is not mine and can't be changed.